# Auth fails on Laravel Passport when calling it from Wordpress wp_remote_post, but works with Postman

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-passport

I am re-asking and updating this question and deleting my old one as the comment went off track.

First time using `Laravel Passport` and I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I am calling an api endpoint from a `Wordpress` site. Both `Passport` and `Laravel 5.7.19` are current versions from a clean install yesterday.

My API is working just fine using `Postman`, with `Passport` authentication.

I call a `Laravel Passport` API from `Wordpress` like this:

```
$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => '45',
    'redirection' => '5',
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer dd4b28b53ea...',
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'email' => $email,
        'channel_url' => $channel_url,
        'api_key' => $api_key,
    ),
    'cookies' => array()
);

// PING API
$response = wp_remote_post( $login, $args );
```

If my route is inside the `auth:api` group like this:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function() {

    Route::post('my/route', 'Api\AuthController@userChannel');

});
```

It fails with `401` on the `wp_remote_post()` call. With `Postman` + `Bearer token` it works.

Taking the route outside of the `auth:api` group works for `Wordpress` and `Postman` and I can log / see the token:

```
[2019-02-11 05:23:32] local.INFo: Bearer dd4b28b53ea...
```

I have tried changes to `.htaccess` file and `php artisan optimize:clear` and `Passport::withoutCookieSerialization();` in `AppServiceProvider` as suggested in numerous posts without success.

The exception at `Laravel`'s side is:

```
The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. {"exception":"[object] (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at /home/vagrant/src/my-app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:215, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The JWT string must have two dots at /home/vagrant/src/my-app/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Parser.php:95)
```

Comment: Is it possible you're using a refresh token instead of an access token? If that's the real beginning of your token, it doesn't look quite right (a jwt isn't a hexidecimal string)

Comment: Travis, I found it two hours ago. I screwed up code in my Laravel controller and it was truncating the token. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Travis mentions there is nothing wrong with my code above. I had a logic issue in my controller. The code above works as it should.